# Python - Como fazer um packet logger de um servidor?

Tags: python

## Python - Como fazer um packet logger de um servidor?

Olá, eu queria saber como faço para criar um packet logger em python que teria a seguinte funcionalidade:

- Receber informações do servidor do jogo, **Exemplo**: **eu cliquei em um botao ele teria que retornar o pacote que o servidor enviou para representar essa ação**

Quais **módulos** eu teria que usar para que eu podesse fazer esse programa?

**Obs**: Caso não entenda oque eu quis dizer com o post, comente oque não entendeu para eu explicar melhor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sua pergunta é bem ampla, então vamos por partes. Se tu quer apenas um logger, tu consegue rodar a lib logging do Python 2.7/3.X para capturar estes detalhes e coloca-los em um arquivo de log.

Você já consegue printar e receber estes detalhes de rede? Se sim, tu conseguiria apenas adicionar o logging por simples linhas de código.

Aqui está a lib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: Com ela biblioteca logging eu consigo capturar um log recebido ao ter clicado em um botão ou uma ação ?

Comment: Você consegue, se tu configura-la para isso! Leia a documentação da biblioteca e tu conseguirá fazer isso! Tu usará um commando como `logging.info("Botao clicado")`